# BiqQuery command line load query - using a JSON table schema

Tags: json, csv, google-bigquery

I'm trying to load a comma separated test file, 'Davetest.csv', and use a JSON schema held in the file 'testjson.json'

However I can't get it to recognize the table schema parameter properly.

```
load mydataset.testy gs://paps1/davetest.csv gs://paps1/testjson.json
```

gives me

> BigQuery error in load operation: Invalid value for:
>   //PAPS1/TESTJSON.JSON is not a valid value

I tried it without the path for the table schema (i.e.load mydataset.testy gs://paps1/davetest.csv testjson.json), and this confused it into thinking I was trying to write the schema inline with a first fieldname of 'testjson.json', and so failed on that as well.

Both of the files are held on GCS in the same bucket.

Obviously I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, but all the code examples I've seen are using the structure above, as far as I can tell.

Could anyone advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think documentation for "bq Command-Line Tool"  is not clear enough!
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#creatingtablefromfile

Rather, check examples by running > *bq help load*
They are more specific in showing allowed options for schema:

```
Examples:  
bq load ds.new_tbl ./info.csv ./info_schema.json  
bq load ds.new_tbl gs://mybucket/info.csv ./info_schema.json  
bq load ds.small gs://mybucket/small.csv name:integer,value:string  
bq load ds.small gs://mybucket/small.csv field1,field2,field3
```

As you can see now, schema file is expected to be local to bq tool

And, of course using inline text schema is still option if local file is somehow doesnt fit in your design

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To circumvent this, I tried to load the schema file from a local disk and that worked.